# If VPS1 fails or send some task to VPS2, how do I make VPS2 work on that automatically?

Tags: bash, vps

What I want to achieve :

If VPS1 fails or send some task to VPS2, how do I make VPS2 work on that automatically?

How do send task to VPS2?
How do I make VPS2 work on sent task?
How do I automate this?

For example :

- VPS1 is resolving domains from a file and adding resolved domains to new file.
- If VPS1 fails to resolve, or gives an error.
- Those domains need to be sent to VPS2.
- VPS2 again tries to resolve it.
- And send back the result to VPS1

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: I have tried Cronjob at specific time. Saved the task to performed in new file in VPS1 shared it to VPS2 using mysql, and Grab the data in VPS2 and performed the task. Con -> This happens at specific time set by me, Not when the error or task is assigned